# Can problems with accessing a secondary hard drive be related to linking my user account to my microsoft account?

Tags: hard-drive, windows-8.1, user-accounts

*[updated below]*

I'm working on a PC with windows 8.1 and while installing OneNote 3 months I linked my user account with my Microsoft ID. I'm using a secondary hard drive (d:) to store project files and data from multiple repositories (git/svn).

After installing the latest windows update this Monday (8/3/15), I started having problems with files on drive D. First thing was that my XAMPP (installed on D) notified me that my Apache crashed and couldn't be restarted. After restarting my PC, there was no drive D at all. Restarting a second time (the windows way of fixing things) my drive magically reappeared.

I continued to work for a while until i started my IDE (phpStorm 9, updated from 8 on monday as well) and it froze while indexing project files. Upon checking I realized that D was gone again.

An admin I know told me, that linking my local account to my Microsoft ID is likely to be the reason. Therefor I unlinked my local account again and could continue my work after another restart. The IDE was running until today when it first froze while doing a full project text search and then later, when it told me that it couldn't save changes to the file I was working on because the file (cached version of the actual file, created by the IDE) was missing.

On both accounts restarting the PC solved the problem. I'm about to format c and start fresh but I'm intrigued... how does linking my local account to my Microsoft id cause such disastrous errors and mess with my local files?

## [update 1]

I'm running *ManageEngine - Desktop Central* (for windows) and I know from 2 colleagues that their Linux machines had problems shutting down after the installation of Desktop Central (for Linux).

A new version of Desktop Central was installed on my PC last Friday and since then I have the same problem with my Windows system when restarting or shutting down the PC (shutdown process keeps running forever until hard shut down / power down). Could this be related to the original problem?

Comment: It sounds like your secondary HDD actually is starting to fail, I have none of these problems, and every device I have has external storage devices and the local account connected to my MS account.

Comment: that was my first thought as well... sounds like a typical hardware failure

Comment: added more details to my original question [update 1]

Comment: Why would a piece of software running on Linux have an affect on Windows when the Linux software wasn't even running.

Comment: Because a windows equivalent of said software is running under windows as well. I thought that was clear but I'll change the wording to prevent further misunderstandings. Thank you, @Ramhound, for bringing this up.

Comment: Could it be related , I suppose, easy enough to confirm.  You should start your PC with a minimal configuration, and configure it so Desktop Central is configured not to automatically start, if you still have the problem then it isn't Desktop Central